# why I get this error in flutter when I change my listview direction for vertical to horizontal

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

Assertion failed: file:///D:/flutterfiles/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1982:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#3c329 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

its because `Listview` needs a horizontal size. You can wrap it in a `Container()` with specified `width` (use `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` for full width of screen).

Comment: it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share your code?